# Oracle - select (complex query) into user-defined collection

Tags: database, oracle

Is it possibe to select some data into user-defined collection? I've created the same structure of record as query returns and then try to select data into my table.

```
procedure MY_PROC(md number, pPERIOD date) is 
TYPE MainRecType IS RECORD (
  addr varchar2(100),
  custom x_custom_table.custom%type,      
  id_cn number,
  iddb_cn number
);
TYPE MainTable IS TABLE OF MainRecType
  INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;  

begin

  select * bulk collect into MainTable from //ERROR!
  (
    select a.address addr, x.custom custom, b.id id_cn, b.id_db iddb_cn
    from AddressTable a, x_custom_table x, BuildTable b
    where a.id_build=b.id and a.id_x=x.id and b.period=pPeriod and b.md=md
  );      

end;
```

It says `PLS-00321: expression 'MainTable' is inappropriate as the left hand side`. If it's possible, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MainTable` is a collection type.  You would need to declare an instance of that collection type to fetch data into

```
procedure MY_PROC(md number, pPERIOD date) 
is 
  TYPE MainRecType IS RECORD (
    addr varchar2(100), 
    custom x_custom_table.custom%type,      
    id_cn number,
    iddb_cn number
  );
  TYPE MainTable IS TABLE OF MainRecType
    INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;  
  l_collection MainTable;
begin
  select a.address addr, x.custom custom, b.id id_cn, b.id_db iddb_cn
    bulk collect into l_collection 
    from AddressTable a, 
         x_custom_table x, 
         BuildTable b
   where a.id_build=b.id 
     and a.id_x=x.id 
     and b.period=pPeriod 
     and b.md=md;

end;
```

Of course, I assume that in your actual code you will do something with the collection once you populate it.

Comment: I can't imagine that it was so silly mistake! Thank you.